# Agent shall wait specific time on arrival to target location

Tags: anylogic

[image]

I have an Agent (AGV) marked as a Ressourceunit
My Goal is that when the Agent enters his destination it waits 55 seconds before it continous with other task.

I tried to write code inside the properties "on arrival to target location" like:

```
double delaytime = 55;
TimeUnits.SECOND.sleep(delaytime);
```

or

```
double delaytime = 55;
hold(delaytime, TimeUnits.SECOND);
```

but both did not work.

Does someone has an Idea, how to solf this Problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Material handling library transporters or normal Agents from a normal resource pool? Also, where did you write that code? (Always add full details and screenshots ideally, helps us help you, see https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow )

Comment: normal agents from a normal resource pool. I added a picture in the question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use code to create time delays. You need to use process blocks.

In your case, you could create a separate process flow with an `Enter`, `Delay` and `Exit` block on `Main` and set them up so that `FTF` agents flow through.

In your "on arrival to target location" code section, you can send the `FTF` agent to the flow using `main.myEnterBlock.take(this)`, assuming `FTF` agents are embedded in `Main` (else adjust the code accordingly).

Note that the flow must be outside of the `FTF` agent, you cannot send yourself inside of yourself :)

Note also that the `FTF` agent must be outside of another flow when you push it into this new flow. So you may need to adjust how and where  you send it over. Maybe you can integrate the `Delay` block into an existing flow...

It all depends on the details